# checkSelfPermission() doesn't seem to work for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I have the app that uses
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

It's automatically granted on Android 6.0, but I can revoke it in the settings.
Wanted to check if it's granted in case user revokes it, so I do this:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //OK permission granted, let's do stuff
} else {
    //I'll better ask for permission
}
```

Funny thing is that the condition is ALWAYS fulfilled, even the permission was revoked manually. And the the app fails... It looks like a bug to me, is it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing something: a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher.

If your `targetSdkVersion` is 22 or lower, you have no ability to determine whether a permission was granted or revoked by the user from Settings.