# How setting android:targetSdkVersion influences requestPermissions()

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-permissions

I just noticed that if `targetSDKVersion` value is not set (this happens when you choose in the project settings that the target framework is the SDK version) then calling `requestPermissions` ALWAYS returns permission granted.

This behavior is mentioned also here: [checkSelfPermission() doesn't seem to work for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525800/checkselfpermission-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-write-external-storage)

Because of this, it started me thinking that a good practice is to actually set `targetSDKVersion`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation from Android developers said about `targetSDKVersion` :

> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.
>   This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).

If you don't set it, by default it's equal to the minSdkVersion providing some unexpected behavior for the latest versions of Android. **So, it's a good practice to define your targetSDKVersion.**